# Extend AD users in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, active-directory, asp.net-core-identity, microsoft-identity-platform

I developed a SPA app(React and .NET Core) that runs only on our corporate intranet(It's hosted locally). Currently, we are authenticating the users against AD using LDAP.

These are my objectives:

1. Users do not need to register as every employee should be able to access the app.
2. We prefer to use SSO authentication method
3. I need to be able to get a list of the users that are in a specific role

I need to create some tables that stores additional information about users. For example, their roles, paths they're allowed to browse, etc. I am not sure how to do this without duplicating the users in ASP.NET Core Identity. I know If I use Identity, I can extend the users and customize them. But I do not want to register users/manage their passwords through Identity. Is there an alternative? Can I eliminate passwords if I used Identity?

I am not familiar with AD or Azure AD as a different team handles our IT needs. But I did a test in Visual Studio, I created a new web project with Authentication Type set to Microsoft Identity Platform. It was amazing that Visual Studio did all the work on my behalf to create an tenant on Azure. When I ran the app it used SSO and I was logged in. Can I use Microsoft Identity Platform with a customized user table? I just need to have a unique identifier for each user to link it with my other tables. I also do not want to manage the users if that's possible.